# Xml multimedia content download

Tags: xml, windows-phone-7, multimedia

I iwant to know the best way to read an xml file and save the content in a windows phone memory.

The xml is available in this link:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/32613258/xml_example.xml

The xml file have links to multimedia files like videos, images and sound. I already make the download of the xml file to the memory phone and i know how to read the file, but i don't know    how to read the content and save it into the memory phone.

I want to read the xml from the memory and pick all the links in the xml and then download the images, videos and sound into memory. What is the best way to do that? I save the files in isolated storage it's possible save in a card memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you get the links from your XML file:

```cs
    // using local XML file for demonstration
    StreamResourceInfo info = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("xml_example.xml", UriKind.Relative));

    XElement xml = XElement.Load(info.Stream);
    // iterate media files
    foreach (XElement element in xml.Element("graphics").Elements("file"))
    {   
        // pick a video
        if (element.Attribute("type").Value == "video")
        {
            // demoing that we found something
            MessageBox.Show(element.Element("fileurl").Value);

            // here goes the real action
            DoSomethingUsefulWithURL(element.Element("fileurl").Value); 
        }

    }
```

And then you proceed with downloading and playing the file as described in this blog post: "[Download, Store and Play Media files from Isolated Storage](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=586)". Your starting point is the URL you got from the XML file. And then the guy from the blog does pretty much the same as you want.

Comment: thanks;) works very nice;) a simple example and simple to understand;) works like a charm;)

Comment: in the case of images i have more than one link.. I want to store all the links for later use it in other place.. Right now the xml have only 4 images but possible in future have 10 or more. So i want to save the links for later save the content into memory. can you help me? i don't know if i store the items in a array or something like that.. Or maybe create a classe to images, another to video and other to audio, and save the atributtes to the class. Hope you unsderstand my english;)

Comment: You could save the links in e.g. a `List<string>` and save it in the application state. See here for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7790698/save-and-retrieve-lists-in-phoneapplicationservice-state/7842264#7842264